# Вывод данных из одной таблицы в другую Java

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc

Как мне сделать вывод данных из одной таблицы в другую? БД MySQL
У меня есть пара таблиц, но мне нужно для начала понять сделать хотя бы с двумя.
Таблицы связаны в Еклипсе. 
Есть таблица 1-я в которую я хочу вывести данные из 2-й таблицы
Есть поля в двух таблицах "Тип номера"
Мне нужно из 2-й таблицы вывести данные в 1-ю таблицу в это поле.

Что мне нужно для этого сделать чтобы данные добавлялись в форму на странице автоматически?

Вот проктект [MyProject.rar](http://rgho.st/6t8ZTpGM9)

Вот некоторые файлы

GuestsDao1

```
package com.honchar.springmvc.dao;
import java.util.List;
import com.honchar.springmvc.model.Guests;

public interface GuestsDao1 {
    Guests findById (int id);
    void saveGuests(Guests guests);
    void deleteGuestsById(int id);
    List<Guests> findAllGuests();
    Guests findGuestsById(int id);

}
```

GuestsDaoImpl

```
package com.honchar.springmvc.dao;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.honchar.springmvc.model.*;

@Repository("guestsDao1")
public class  GuestsDaoImpl1 extends AbstractDao<Integer, Guests> implements GuestsDao1 {
    public Guests findById (int id) {
        return getByKey(id);
    }
    public void saveGuests(Guests guests) {
        persist(guests);
    }
    public void deleteGuestsById(int id) {
        Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("delete from Guests where id = :id");
        query.setInteger("id", id);
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Guests> findAllGuests() {
        Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
        return (List<Guests>) criteria.list();
    }

    public Guests findGuestsById(int id) {
        Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
        return (Guests) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }
}
```

GuestsService1

```
package com.honchar.springmvc.service;

import java.util.List;
import com.honchar.springmvc.model.Guests;

public interface GuestsService1 {
    Guests findById (int id);
    void saveGuests(Guests guests);
    void updateGuests(Guests guests);
    void deleteGuestsById(int id);
    List<Guests> findAllGuests();
    Guests findGuestsById(int id);
    boolean isGuestsIdUinque(Integer id);
}
```

GuestsServiceImpl1

```
package com.honchar.springmvc.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.honchar.springmvc.dao.GuestsDao1;
import com.honchar.springmvc.model.Guests;
import com.honchar.springmvc.model.*;

@Service("guestsService1")
@Transactional
public class GuestsServiceImpl1 implements GuestsService1 {

    @Autowired
    private GuestsDao1 dao;

    public Guests findById(int id) {
        return dao.findById(id);
    }

    public void saveGuests(Guests guests) {
        dao.saveGuests(guests);
    }
    public void updateGuests(Guests guests) {
        Guests entity = dao.findById(guests.getId());
        if(entity!=null){
            entity.setSurname(guests.getSurname());
            entity.setName(guests.getName());
            entity.setType_rooms(guests.getType_rooms());
            entity.setNumber_room(guests.getNumber_room());
            entity.setAdditional_Service(guests.getAdditional_Service());
            entity.setSpending_Types(guests.getSpending_Types());
            entity.setNumber_phone(guests.getNumber_phone());
            entity.setPayment(guests.getPayment());
            entity.setType_cards(guests.getType_cards());
            entity.setNumber_cards(guests.getNumber_cards());
            entity.setAmount_payment(guests.getAmount_payment());
            entity.setDate(guests.getDate());
        }
    }

    public void deleteGuestsById(int id) {
        dao.deleteGuestsById(id);
    }

    public List<Guests> findAllGuests() {
        return dao.findAllGuests();
    }

    public Guests findGuestsById(int id) {
        return dao.findGuestsById(id);
    }

    public boolean isGuestsIdUinque(Integer id) {
        Guests guests = findGuestsById(id);
        return ( guests == null || ((id != null) && (guests.getId() == id)));
    }

}
```

Страница на которую я хочу чтобы данные выводились в поле "Тип номера" .jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Реєстрація Гостей</title>

<style>

    .error {
        color: #ff0000;
    }
    body {
        font-family: sans-serif;}
    a{
        text-decoration: none;}
</style>

</head>

<body>

     <h2>Реєстраційна Форма</h2>

    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="guests">
        <form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id"/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="surname">Прізвище: </label> </td>
                <td><form:input path="surname" id="surname"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="surname" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>

        <tr>
                <td><label for="name">Ім'я: </label> </td>
                <td><form:input path="name" id="name"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="type_rooms">Тип кімнат: </label> </td>
                <td><form:input path="type_rooms" id="type_rooms"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="type_rooms" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label for="number_room">Номер кімнати: </label> </td>
                <td><form:input path="number_room" id="number_room"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="number_room" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label for="additional_Service">Додаткові послуги: </label> </td>
                <td><form:input path="additional_Service" id="additional_Service"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="additional_Service" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label for="spending_Types">Типи витрат: </label> </td>
                <td><form:input path="spending_Types" id="spending_Types"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="spending_Types" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="number_phone">Номер телефону: </label> </td>
                <td><form:input path="number_phone" id="number_phone"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="number_phone" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="payment">Тип Оплати: </label> </td>
                <td><form:input path="payment" id="payment"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="payment" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="type_cards">Тип картки: </label> </td>
                <td><form:input path="type_cards" id="type_cards"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="type_cards" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="number_cards">Номер картки: </label> </td>
                <td><form:input path="number_cards" id="number_cards"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="number_cards" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="amount_payment">Сума до оплати: </label> </td>
                <td><form:input path="amount_payment" id="amount_payment"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="amount_payment" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="date">Дата реєстрації: </label> </td>
                <td><form:input path="date" id="date"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="date" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${edit}">
                            <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise >
                            <input type="submit" value="Реєстрація"/>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Повернутися до <a href="<c:url value='/list' />">Списку з гостями</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Таблица Guests в которою нужно внести данные "Она и есть основание этой страницы что выше"

```
package com.honchar.springmvc.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.validation.constraints.Digits;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;


@Entity
@Table(name="GUESTS")
public class Guests implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "SURNAME")
    private String surname;

    @Size(min=3, max=50)
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "TYPE_ROOMS")
    private String type_rooms;

    @Column(name = "NUMBER_ROOM")
    private int number_room;

    @Column(name = "ADDITIONAL_SERVICE")
    private String additional_Service;

    @Column(name = "SPENDING_TYPES")
    private String spending_Types;

    @Column(name = "NUMBER_PHONE")
    private int number_phone;

    @Column(name = "PAYMENT")
    private String payment;

    @Column(name = "TYPE_CARDS")
    private String type_cards;

    @Column(name = "NUMBER_CARDS")
    private int number_cards;

    @NotNull
    @Digits(integer=8, fraction=2)
    @Column(name = "AMOUNT_PAYMENT", nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal amount_payment;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy") 
    @Column(name = "DATE" )
    private Date date;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="guests", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<types_of_rooms> type_of_rooms;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="guests", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<type_of_payment> type_payment;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="guests", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<type_of_cards> types_cards;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="guests", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<spending_types> types_spending;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="guests", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<additional_services> add_services;

    public Guests() {

    }

    public Guests(String surname, String name, String type_rooms, int number_room, String additional_Service, 
            String spending_Types, int number_phone,String payment,String type_cards,
            int number_cards, BigDecimal amount_payment, Date date) {
        this.surname = surname;
        this.name = name;
        this.type_rooms = type_rooms;
        this.number_room = number_room;
        this.additional_Service = additional_Service; 
        this.spending_Types = spending_Types;
        this.number_phone = number_phone;
        this.payment = payment;
        this.type_cards = type_cards;
        this.number_cards = number_cards;
        this.amount_payment = amount_payment;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name =  name;
    }

    public String getType_rooms() {
        return type_rooms;
    }
    public void setType_rooms(String type_rooms) {
        this.type_rooms = type_rooms;
    }

    public int getNumber_room() {
        return number_room;
    }
    public void setNumber_room(int number_room) {
        this.number_room = number_room;
    }

    public String getAdditional_Service() {
        return additional_Service;
    }
    public void setAdditional_Service(String additional_Service) {
        this.additional_Service = additional_Service;
    }

    public String getSpending_Types() {
        return spending_Types;
    }
    public void setSpending_Types(String spending_Types) {
        this.spending_Types =  spending_Types;
    }

    public int getNumber_phone() {
        return number_phone;
    }
    public void setNumber_phone(int number_phone) {
        this.number_phone = number_phone;
    }

    public String getPayment() {
        return payment;
    }
    public void setPayment(String payment) {
        this.payment = payment;
    }

    public String getType_cards() {
        return type_cards;
    }
    public void setType_cards(String type_cards) {
        this.type_cards = type_cards;
    }

    public int getNumber_cards() {
        return number_cards;
    }
    public void setNumber_cards(int number_cards) {
        this.number_cards = number_cards;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount_payment() {
        return amount_payment;
    }
    public void setAmount_payment(BigDecimal amount_payment) {
        this.amount_payment = amount_payment;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date =  date;
    }

    public List<types_of_rooms> getType_of_rooms() {
        return type_of_rooms;
    }
    public void setTypes_of_rooms(List<types_of_rooms> type_of_rooms) {
        this.type_of_rooms = type_of_rooms; 
    }

    public  List<type_of_payment> getType_payment() {
        return type_payment;
    }
    public void setType_payment(List<type_of_payment> type_payment) {
        this.type_payment = type_payment;   
    }

    public  List<type_of_cards> getTypes_cards() {
        return types_cards;
    }
    public void setTypes_cards(List<type_of_cards> types_cards) {
        this.types_cards = types_cards; 
    }

    public  List<spending_types> getTypes_spending() {
        return types_spending;
    }
    public void setTypes_spending(List<spending_types> types_spending) {
        this.types_spending = types_spending;   
    }
    public  List<additional_services> getAdd_services() {
        return add_services;
    }
    public void setAdd_service(List<additional_services> add_services) {
        this.add_services = add_services;   
    }


    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Guests [id=" + id +", surname=" + surname + ", name=" + name + 
                ", type_rooms=" + type_rooms + ",additional_Service=" + additional_Service + 
                ", spending_Types=" + spending_Types+ ", number_phone=" + number_phone +",payment=" 
                + payment + ",type_cards=" + type_cards+ ",number_cards=" + number_cards +",amount_payment=" + amount_payment +", date=" + date + "]";
    }

}
```

Таблица Type_of_rooms с которой данные я хочу вывести в поле type_room(Тип номера)

```
    package com.honchar.springmvc.model; 
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;


    @Entity
    @Table(name = "TYPES_OF_ROOMS",catalog = "springmvc")
    public class types_of_rooms implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "ROOMS_ID")
        private long roomsId;

        @Column(name ="TYPE_ROOMS")
        private String type_rooms;

        @ManyToOne(optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "TYPE_ROOMS", referencedColumnName = "TYPE_ROOMS", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private Guests guests;

        public Guests getGuests () {
            return guests;
        }
        public void setGuests(Guests guests) {
            this.guests = guests;
        }

        public long getRoomsId() {
            return roomsId;
        }

        public void setRoomsId (long roomsId) {
            this.roomsId = roomsId;
        }

        public String getType_rooms() {
            return type_rooms;
        }

        public void setType_rooms(String type_rooms) {
            this.type_rooms = type_rooms;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "types_of_rooms [roomsId=" + roomsId + ", type_rooms = " + type_rooms +"]";
        }
    }
```

Что мне нужно дописать или сделать?

Comment: Сначала разберитесь с какой таблицы и как?

Comment: Я хочу чтобы данные со второй таблицы добавлялись в форму на странице (код есть выше JSP), Основанием страницы есть первая таблица "Guests" в ней есть поле type_room. Таблицы связаны по этому полю. Я хочу чтобы данные второй таблицы добавлялись в поле и поле было в виде списка.

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Comment: Незнаю как вывести данные со второй таблицы в форму в поле "Тип номера"

Comment: Я хочу понять как вывести данные со второй таблицы в форму чтобы потом с остальных вывести

Comment: Что возвращается из списка?

Comment: Я хочу чтобы данные со второй таблицы которые находятся в поле "Тип номера" Добавлялись в форму в то самое поле "Тип номера". Вот и все.

Comment: Как вы хотите чтобы данные добавлялись?

Comment: Ниже я вставил картинку как хочу чтобы данные выглядели.

Comment: А где у вас не работает код?

Comment: Я незнаю как вывести данные в форму чтобы данные были форме как список. Вот что я хочу.

Comment: А данные ввобще то приходят? Может быть вам надо создать объект с данными?

Comment: Какой обьект? С какими данными. И где создать? 
Таблица с данными у меня есть. В MySQL данные и таблица есть.

Comment: У меня не выводиться другая таблица в Еклипсе в консоле когда запускаю сервер.
Поэтому я и спрашиваю что мне нужно сделать. Чтобы все работало.
Я могу скинуть сюда архив с проектом может тогда будет понятно что я сделал.